# matrix.dot(inv(matrix)) isn't equal to identity matrix

Tags: python, matrix, inverse

I'm encountering an issue since hours, I don't understand why the V matrix below doesn't equal the Identity matrix:

```
A = np.random.randint(50, size=(100, 2))
V = A.dot(A.T)
D = V.dot(inv(V))
D
```

The result I found is below either:

```
array([[  3.26611328,   7.87890625,  14.1953125 , ...,   2.        ,
     -5.        , -24.        ],
   [ -5.91061401, -26.05834961,   5.30126953, ..., -10.        ,
      8.        , -16.        ],
   [ -2.64431763,   3.55639648,   3.10107422, ...,  -0.5       ,
     -5.        ,  -4.        ],
   ...,
   [ -2.62512207,  -7.78222656,  10.26367188, ...,  -6.        ,
     18.        ,   0.        ],
   [ -3.0625    ,  14.        ,  -4.        , ...,  -0.0625    ,
      0.        ,   8.        ],
   [  2.        ,  -7.        ,  16.        , ...,  -7.5       ,
     -8.        ,  -4.        ]])
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: "I don't have the identity matrix" - what _does_ it return, exactly? Please include the output in your post

Comment: And it certainly does equal the identity matrix. Say, `x=np.asfarray([[1,3], [4,5]])`, then `np.linalg.inv(x).dot(x)` equals `array([[1.0000000e+00, 4.4408921e-16], [0.0000000e+00, 1.0000000e+00]])`, which is the identity matrix

Comment: I've have added some precisions in my initial question. thank you guys for your help, this is holding since 3 hours ago...

Comment: "the result isn't an identity matrix" - what _is_ that result?? Please include the _result_ in your post

Comment: I've modified my question, I've added the result, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've found my issue:

I was trying to find the inv() of a matrix which det(matrix) = 0, that's why the calculus wasn't correct.

```
D = V.T.dot(V)
inv(D).dot(D)
```

then I find the Identity matrix

Thank you
Habib